# Prove that if $A$, $B$ and $C$ are sets then $(A \Delta B) \cup C = (A \cup C) \Delta (B \setminus C) $

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've been trying to solve this problem for hours and I can't come up with a solution that isn't so complicated and ugly to the point where I feel like I'm doing something wrong. Here are my attempts:

1. Trying to show that both sets are equal to $((A \cap B) \setminus C)^c$, and then show that that implies that the sets are equal. This doesn't work out in practice because that would require showing that set $x$ is a subset of this, and showing that set $y$ is not a subset, etc.
2. Showing that both are subsets of each other. This is the conventional way but this would require showing that some subset of $(A \Delta B) \cup C$ and also a subset of $(A \cup C) \Delta (B \setminus C)$, and so on.

There are many more attempts but I'm just here with a question: Is there a practical way of proving this?

Comment: Is $A\Delta B=(A\cup B)\backslash (A\cap B)$?

Comment: The conventional way should work.  Approach it element by element, rather than working with whole subsets.

Comment: Venn diagram partitions universe into eight sets. Determine for each of the eight whether each of your two sets contains it.

Comment: @KentaS yes it is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume $x \in (A \Delta B) \cup C$.

If $x \in C$, then $x \in A \cup C$ and also $x \notin B \setminus C$.  Therefore, in this case $x \in (A \cup C) \Delta (B \setminus C)$.

Otherwise, $x \notin C$ and $x$ is in exactly one of $A$ or $B$.  If $x \in A$, then $x \in A \cup C$, and also $x \notin B \Rightarrow x \notin B \setminus C$.  Thus, $x \in (A \cup C) \Delta (B \setminus C)$.  If $x \in B$, then $x \notin A, C \Rightarrow x \notin A \cup C$.  But $x \in B, x \notin C \Rightarrow x \in B \setminus C$, so again $x \in (A \cup C) \Delta (B \setminus C)$.

This proves one containment.

Now assume $x \in (A \cup C) \Delta (B \setminus C)$.  Then $x$ is in exactly one of $A \cup C$ and $B \setminus C$.

If $x \in B \setminus C$, then $x \notin C$ by the definition of $\setminus$, and because we know from the previous sentence that $x \notin A \cup C$, we also know that $x \notin A$.   Thus, $x \in A \Delta B$.

Otherwise, $x \in A \cup C$.  If $x \in C$, then necessarily $x \in (A \Delta B) \cup C$.  If $x \notin C$, then $x \in A$ *and also* $x \notin B \setminus C$, which means $x \notin B$ (because $x \in B, x \notin C \Rightarrow x \in B \setminus C$, contradicting our premise).  But then we have $x \in A, x \notin B$, so $x \in A \Delta B \subseteq (A \Delta B) \cup C$.

This proves the reverse containment, so equality holds.

Comment: this is a nice proof, so it's basically all just a big proof by cases?

Comment: @ProPoop Pretty much, but it's much easier if you start with $C$.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of the [characteristic functions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) $a,b,c$ (with values in [the ring $\Bbb Z_2$](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Integers_modulo_n)) of $A,B,C,$ the goal rewrites
$$a+b+c+(a+b)c=a+c+ac+b(1+c),$$
and thus becomes obvious.

Comment: No I am not. Maybe you are not familiar with the elementary tools I used, @ProPoop Please remove your  downvote and don't call me your guy. I will be glad to explain the point(s) you don't grasp.

Comment: I’m sorry for calling you my guy, it’s just that this response is anything but obvious. I’m only studying set theory as part of an intro-to-proofs book so I’m not familiar with anything about your answer. My highest knowledge of math is calc 3.

Comment: I added two links which should help. I am now looking for another one explaining how the set operations are translated algebraically modulo 2.

Comment: Sorry:  I found none. Just notice that the characteristic functions of $A\cap B$ and complement of $A$ are respectively $ab$ and $1+a\bmod2.$ The other set-operations can be expressed in terms of these two, hence translated likewise.